# In IE8, add a new row before the last row to HTML table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, internet-explorer-8, html4

I need to add a new row before the summary row to a table. I able to add a new row before summary row but the problem is some cells have text field elements and some are non-editable. How to create a row taken this into consideration.
 Please find below the code for adding a new row before the last row.

```
<table id="sampTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
             <td><input type="text"/></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
          <tr id="summaryRow">
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
              <td><input type="text"/></td>
             <td><input type="text"/></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>

    <button id="AddBtn" onclick="addTableRow($('#sampTable'));">Add row</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function addTableRow(jQtable){
        jQtable.each(function(){
            var $table = $(this);
            // Number of td's in the last table row
            var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
            var tds = '<tr>';
            for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
                tds += '<td><input type="text" class="tb-input"/></td>';
            }
            tds += '</tr>';
           if($('tbody', this).length > 0){
               // $('tbody', this).append(tds);
               $('tr:last',this).before(tds);
            }else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
  }
</script>
```

The above code adds a text field element for all the columns. I don't need it, as for me some columns contain text fields and some are non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason should be that IE8- has a bad syncronization for DOM added as string.
Often you could resolve by adding a jQuery object instead of a string.

So in your case

```
    var $tds = $('<tr>'); //this create a jQuery object
    /*   other code here   */
    $(this).append(tds); //this add the objet to the DOM
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pasqLisena/83aqdd62/) in order to make it clear.